# Show a nested fragment inside a tabLayout with view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have main activity with 4 tabs in the settings tab I need to implement this flow:

1. The user click on a `recyclerView` item (this has been handled).
2. A new fragment is shown instead of the settings tab.

I tried to make a replace transaction on view pager view, but when the user click on another tab the newly created fragment is still shown and it's not replaced by view pager.

**Edit:** My code for showing the nested fragment:

```
        clickListenr = settingsRecyclerAdapter.observeClickListener()
            .subscribe(id -> {
                if(id == 3){
                    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                            .replace(R.id.view_pager,new WebViewFragment())
                            .addToBackStack(null)
                            .commit();
                }
            });
```

Comment: right now you have a tablayout with 4 tabs attached with viewpager. And for that you have 4 main fragments which are related to the 4 tabs, right?

Comment: @HemantN.Karmur exactly, and from one of those main fragment I need to show a nested fragment

Comment: can you please show me your code that you have done for the nested fragment?

Comment: @HemantN.Karmur I have edited the question.

Comment: okay, got it. Giving you a solution for this.

Comment: I suggest you to use only Framelayout in your main fragment. Then Creat two fragment named like MainFragmentTop and , SettingFragment(nested fragment). Then in your main fragment onviewcreated method relapce your MainFragmentTop fragment into framelayout. Then when you want to open setting fragment replace or add same into framelayout.
So, it's become easier to use.

Comment: got it? or required any help?

Comment: thank you so much got the idea, trying it

Comment: never mind. I'm always ready to help and solve any of the doubts.

Comment: it works like a charm. a little question the transactions when the user clicks should be done on the mainFragment by passing the events from theMainFragmentTop  or on the MainFragmentTop directly?

Comment: main fragment is just only working as a container with using framelayout. So, whatever you want to do it must be done with your MainFragmentTop  or nested fragment.

Comment: for ex., if you want to go at nested fragment from MainFragmentTop then take a event in a MainFragmentTop fragment and work onward. got it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to use only Framelayout in your main fragment. Then Creat two fragment named like MainFragmentTop and , SettingFragment(nested fragment). Then in your main fragment onviewcreated method relapce your MainFragmentTop fragment into framelayout. Then when you want to open setting fragment replace or add same into framelayout. So, it's become easier to use.

This is working fine.